# Get range of records from SQL query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I want to use this SQL query to get only the records between 8 and 10:

```
select *
from(
SELECT a.*,rownum rn 
FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG  a
ORDER BY USERID ASC)
WHERE rn  >= 8 and rn <= 10
```

When I implement this SQL query into pagination I get every time 1 row on the second page no matter how many rows I have configured to be displayed into the pages. Is this SQL query valid?

This is the table structure:

```
-- TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG

CREATE TABLE ACTIVESESSIONSLOG(
  ASESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
  USERID VARCHAR2(30 ),
  ACTIVITYSTART TIMESTAMP(6),
  ACTIVITYEND TIMESTAMP(6),
  ACTIVITY CLOB
)
/
```

Best wishes

Comment: Are you changing the internal query when you look for the second page?

Comment: Query looks correct, but i can't understand what the problem really is.

Comment: Exactly how many rows are returned when you have no WHERE clause?  And exactly what is the query being executed for page 2?  (Not what you know it *should* be, but what did you find when you debugged your code?)

Comment: The code works fine for me too (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7069a/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rownum` is applied before the `ORDER BY` so your query is almost certainly not doing what you expect.  Your query is essentially asking for an arbitrary 3 rows and the `ORDER BY` isn't doing anything useful.

You could use the analytic function `row_number` instead, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               row_number() over (order by userid asc) rn
          FROM activeSessionsLog a)
 WHERE rn BETWEEN 8 AND 10
```

which will page through the results

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select empno, ename, job
  2    from (select e.*,
  3                 row_number() over (order by empno) rn
  4            from emp e)
  5*  where rn between 1 and 3
SQL> /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select empno, ename, job
  2    from (select e.*,
  3                 row_number() over (order by empno) rn
  4            from emp e)
  5*  where rn between 4 and 8
SQL> /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select empno, ename, job
  2    from (select e.*,
  3                 row_number() over (order by empno) rn
  4            from emp e)
  5*  where rn between 9 and 11
SQL> /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK
```

It may be more efficient, however, to do something like this where Oracle can use the inner `rownum <= 10` predicate to know that it can stop sorting the data once it has identified the first 10 rows.

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum rn
          FROM (SELECT a.*
                  FROM activeSessionsLog a
                 ORDER BY userid asc) b
         WHERE rownum <= 10) c
 WHERE rn >= 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Oracle 12c you can now use offset/fetch clause.

You can now write queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_objects
ORDER object_name
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Please review this [new feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html) and also consider the improvements in the execution plan.