# How do I get N rows in Oracle SQL SELECT statement given number by variable?

Tags: oracle, select, oracle19c

In Oracle SQL, I have a variable that is the number of rows to fetch, I can only use SQL SELECT statement, so no PL/SQL block.

If the variable has a value set I must fetch the number of rows in the variable, if not then fetch as many rows as possible (infinite).

I tried:

```sql
select * from system_options
THEN FETCH FIRST
    CASE :lim
        THEN :lim
        ELSE 9999
    END
ROWS ONLY
```

This gives me a `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Another option would be by not having the variable set then not having the `THEN FETCH` statement.

Comment: I guess this question is a duplicate and similar to the below me [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10091780/15342690)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors:

- You do not need the `THEN` before the `FETCH FIRST`; and
- The `CASE` expression is missing a `WHEN` clause.

I don't have SQL/Plus to hand to test using a bind variable but something like this:

```sql
select * from system_options
FETCH FIRST CASE WHEN :lim IS NOT NULL THEN :lim ELSE 9999 END ROWS ONLY
```

Or, you can use `COALESCE`:

```sql
select * from system_options
FETCH FIRST COALESCE( :lim, 9999 ) ROWS ONLY
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=49f4d4fa8ab366f24070c2c5f31b7c00)*

Comment: Using `COALESCE` is better, thank  you! I though Oracle would have a constant for max int or something, but well, I have to type a number. Also I don't know why in my case I have to use a string, so I have to use `'9999'` or else I get this error `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER`.

Comment: @user5507535 If your bind variable is passed as a string then both data types will need to be the same and it will complain if they are not. I'm assuming you are passing it from a 3rd party application (such as Java, C# or Python); if so then just ensure its bound as (or cast to) a number and not as a string.